# Difference between library and framework in Angular Material and Bootstrap?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, frameworks

I have hard time understanding if I got it correct, why Angular Material is library while bootstrap is framework.

What makes it this way?

Comment: hope this might help, https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library-bd133054023f/

Answer (score 1):

Comparison between Angular Material and Bootstrap

Angular Material and Bootstrap are both front-end frameworks that provide pre-designed UI components and styles to help developers build responsive and attractive user interfaces however they both differ from

- Architecture
- Design Philosophy
- Customization provided
- Predefined components Material (specifically designed for angular integration)
- Learning curve

However from generic POV both serves the the purpose to build interactive UI's. Both frameworks have their strengths and weaknesses, and the choice between them will depend on the specific needs of the project and the preferences of the development and need of requirement.